# HTML parser for phrase and case sensitive searches, in Java

Tags: java, html, parsing, search, html-parsing

I would like to know if there are any HTML Parsers in Java that would support phrase and case sensitive searches.
All I need to know is number of hits in a html page for searched phrase and support for case sensitivity.

Thanks,
Sharma

Comment: @Sean Sorry, I dint know it must be Java, is there any specific reason?

Comment: because it's a name, not an acronym/abbreviation (as opposed to PERL, for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

does not it help, if you take html page as text, strip html tags:

```
String noHTMLString = htmlString.replaceAll("\\<.*?\\>", "");
```

and now [count](http://www.kodejava.org/examples/89.html) what you need in noHTMLString ? It could be helpful, if you have html page with markup like:

```
this is <span>cool</span>
```

and you need to look for text "is cool" (because prev html page will be transformed into "this is cool" string). To count you can use StringUtils from [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/download_lang.cgi), it has special method called [countMatches](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#countMatches%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29). Everything together should work as:

```
String htmlString = "this is <span>cool</span>";    
String noHTMLString = htmlString.replaceAll("\\<.*?\\>", "");
int count = StringUtils.countMatches( noHTMLString, "is cool");
```

I would go with that approach, at least give it a try. It sounds better than parsing html, and then traversing it looking for words you need...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [this](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/)?

You can search the text using regular expressions.